# Karma plugin 'jasmine-matchers' added to karma.conf.js frameworks, still doesn't load in unit tests

Tags: angularjs, npm, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I haven't been able to find much documentation on this issue. Despite installing karma-jasmine-matchers and including it in frameworks [per instruction](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-matchers), I still can't use any of the supplied methods. Has anyone run into this issue and found a solution?

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
   config.set({
     // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
     basePath: '',

     // testing framework to use
     frameworks: [
       'jasmine',
       'jasmine-matchers'
     ],

     more config stuff...
```

The error I get when I run this a test using any method is:

```
 "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect({
   memberName: undefined
 }).toHaveMember('memberName')')"
```

**Update:**
Was a [version issue](https://github.com/JamieMason/karma-jasmine-matchers/issues/7).

Comment: Looks like this issue ~ https://github.com/JamieMason/karma-jasmine-matchers/issues/7. Check the version that you have installed

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thanks! I'm not sure why that didn't show up in my googling.

Comment: Thanks to StackOverflow, it will show up for others now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have added a working example at https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers/tree/master/examples/karma but it looks like you also needed to define it under plugins. it seems if *any* plugins are defined in karma, they then all need defining.